# How to update Listview item position when I updating listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I creating dialog and into dialog given a list of items. and also on dialog I have added search functionality. when I clicking on items its get correct item position but when I search list its not updated with data items rather I can't retrieve exactly clickable items.
Following is my Code.

```
public void uploadFromDirve(View vi) {
    EditText et;

    //setContentView(R.layout.list_dialog);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listDialog = new Dialog(Project_Define_Activity.this);
    listDialog.setTitle("Select Item");
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) Project_Define_Activity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_dialog, null, false);
    listDialog.setContentView(v); 
    listDialog.setCancelable(true);

    //there are a lot of <span id="IL_AD7" class="IL_AD">settings</span>, for dialog, <span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">check</span> them all out!
    ListView list1 = (ListView) listDialog.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);

    et=(EditText)listDialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_Search);
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            Project_Define_Activity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }


    });

    //list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Project_Define_Activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names));
    //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to <span id="IL_AD2" class="IL_AD">show</span> it

    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, final int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Project_Define_Activity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Attach file "+arg2)
            .setPositiveButton("Attach ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    System.out.println("OK CLICKED");
                    Log.e("Selected", names.get(arg2));
                    fileflag = 1;
                    fileindex = arg2;
                    listDialog.cancel();

                    nameOfFile.setText(names.get(arg2));
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    listDialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.show();

        }

    });

    listDialog.show();



}
```

Answer (score 3):

for updating the data you can either notify the dataset changed-

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or the another alternative is that clear your array list which you are populating in adapter and update the array list with new values and populate it back like-

```
ArrayList<String> print_copy=new ArrayList<String();
```

than clear and again assign new values

```
print_copy.clear();
print_copy.add(data);
print_copy.add(data);
```

and populate it again.

Thanks